# updating timestamp field in mysql using joomla component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm working on joomla component **(com_book) version 3.0**. In that I'm trying to insert books using *form* to *database*, in database I'm having `updated_at` column for that column I'm using `timestamp datatype`. Here `updated_at` column working fine when i'm inserting and updating books using database and inserting books using forms then it's working fine but when I'm trying updating books using forms that time `update_at` column not updating.

Can anyone explain what mistake I made in that process?

Comment: please provide your update statement?

Comment: updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; This statement i am using for that updated_at coloumn.

Comment: Can you place your query in the question so we can figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Another method is creating a custom field for that,

use this field code in your book.xml form file

```
<fieldset
addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_book/models/fields"
>
..
..
<field name="timestamp" type="lastmodified"
label="" description="" />
..
..
</fieldset>
```

and create a file called, lastmodified.php
in your /administrator/components/com_book/models/fields folder

```
<?php

defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

/**
 * Supports an HTML form field
 */
class JFormFieldLastModified extends JFormField
{
    /**
     * The form field type.
     *
     * @var        string
     * @since    1.6
     */
    protected $type = 'lastmodified';

    /**
     * Method to get the field input lastmodified.
     *
     */
    protected function getInput()
    {
        // Initialize variables.
        $html = array();
        $old_time_updated = $this->value;
        if ($old_time_updated) {
            $jdate = new JDate($old_time_updated);
            $pretty_date = $jdate->format(JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC2'));
        }
        $time_updated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $html = '<input type="hidden" name="'.$this->name.'" value="'.$time_updated.'" />';

        return $html;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste this function in the Table file, of your table for example
Joomla-Root/Administrator/com_book/table/book.php
if there is already a store function, then edit that and add these lines alone man, that will do the job,

```
    public function store($updateNulls = false)
{
    $date   = JFactory::getDate();
               // this is your primary key maybe id or book_id
    if ($this->book_id) {
        // Assigning the last modified date to your timestamp field
        $this->timestamp    = $date->toSql();
    }

    // Attempt to store the user data. - just leave the rest to parent function
    return parent::store($updateNulls);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In save function after data binding you can set the `updated_at`

```
// Bind the data to the table
if (!$table->bind($post))
{
//display error
}
//after binding write this line-
$table->updated_at  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

let me know if this not work.

Comment: Hello Irfan,I am using joomla version 3.0.In that components no need to write save funtion.so i don't have save function in my component.

Answer (score 0):

The Joomla Component Creator can build Joomla 3.0 components and save you messing with simple stuff like this.

Take a look: http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/

It's free for one table. If nothing else you can copy paste code from that or peak and see how to develop yourself.